# Not able to enable oozie web console

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, oozie, hadoop2, cloudera-cdh

I am using CDH 5.7 on RHEL 7.2. I followed below link [Oozie webconsole](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/admin_oozie_console.html#admin_oozie_console).
After copying ext-2.2 to /var/lib/oozie, i changed permissions to 755. Then i restarted oozie. But still it is showing Oozie web console is disables

Comment: And? That's it? You must have tried something. I see [completely different instructions for activating it from the command line](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cdh_ig_oozie_configure.html#concept_dxx_tj5_cn).

Comment: ya tried that too, almost same instructions in both pages (i ma not using Kerberos)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found answer

1. Download ext-2.2
2. Extract and move to /var/lib/oozie
3. Change owner to oozie and apply permissions 755
4. Then Restart oozie